# Separation of users and posts microservices?

Tags: architecture, microservices

Currently there is a users microservice in my project, which handles all the authentication logic and stores user data (email, name, bio etc.)

One of my application's features will be posts. I want posts to be contained in a separate microservice, which will use a separate database, storing just the user ID. However, that would require doing two HTTP calls:

- One to get new posts
- Another one to get user details for each post author

It is big overhead, when just updating the feed. Maybe it is worth to combine the microservices, or to use one database for both posts and users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most of the answers in the field of architecture - there is no "correct" way, it's all about trade-offs and what you're willing to pay.

For example - separating the posts and users to be consumed from 2 different services actually causes http calls overhead as you mentioned, on the other hand - deployment, testing, and maintenance in general will be much easier if you have 2 different services - a small change in the users service has no impact on the posts application. If you combine them to one service - you can't enjoy these advantages.

As a rule of thumb (but again, it's not true for **all** cases) - in microservices, a different response's model usually indicates on a different service (again - ease of deployment, testing, and maintenance), so it makes sense for me to separate the users and posts services. However one thing you can combine is the database - you can put users and posts in the same database, but in different tables of course. In that way you're still separating the models, but enjoying the privilege of have the data in the same repository (joining tables, etc.).

In addition, if you're really concerned about the http calls from posts service to users service, you can consider caching which will help to reduce the calls overhead.

Comment: Sharing the database is one of the biggest bad practices for microservices. it will kill many benefit you would expect from microservice architecture like development isolation, scalability etc.

Comment: @cool Defining shared database as a bad practice is wrong and misleading. It might be hard to scale up with this pattern, however there are other advantages like simplicity, consistency, and more. It all depends on the use-case and about the architecture characteristics which are important for you, but in general this is a completely valid pattern: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html

Comment: you are right that it is a pattern people use from time to time especially newcomers to microservices world and for some particular usecases with or without knowing any alternative better solution. But that doesn't change that it is an anti-pattern and bad practice. There are quite useful resources out there if you would like to investigate why.